# OpenAPI PHP client giving Fatal Error with anyOf

Tags: php, polymorphism, swagger, openapi, openapi-generator

I'm trying to make an OpenAPI autogenerated PHP client using `anyOf` and `allOf` properties.

The goal is to be able to return an array with polymorphism in it: objects of different types.
Also those objects have a common base object as well.

In my example schema, `Items` is an array which items can be of types `ItemOne` or `ItemTwo`.
Both types of items have an own property (`itemOneProperty` and `itemTwoProperty`, respectively), and a common property `baseItemProperty` (which is inherited from `BaseItem` with the `allOf` keyword).

Here you have the API specification yaml:

```yaml
openapi: 3.0.0
info:
  title: Test API
  version: 1.0.0
servers:
  - url: https://api.myjson.com/bins

paths:
  /roxgd:
    get:
      operationId: getItems
      responses:
        '200':
          description: Success
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                $ref: '#/components/schemas/Items'
components:
  schemas:

    Items:
      type: array
      items:
        anyOf:
          - $ref: '#/components/schemas/ItemOne'
          - $ref: '#/components/schemas/ItemTwo'

    BaseItem:
      type: object
      properties:
        baseItemProperty:
          type: string

    ItemOne:
      allOf:
        - $ref: '#/components/schemas/BaseItem'
        - type: object
          properties:
            itemOneProperty:
              type: string

    ItemTwo:
      allOf:
        - $ref: '#/components/schemas/BaseItem'
        - type: object
          properties:
            itemTwoProperty:
              type: string
```

This is the endpoint I'm sending the requests: https://api.myjson.com/bins/roxgd

And it returns this example json:

```yaml
[
    {
        type: "ItemOne",
        baseItemProperty: "foo1",
        itemOneProperty: "bar1"
    },
    {
        type: "ItemTwo",
        baseItemProperty: "foo2",
        itemTwoProperty: "bar2"
    }
]
```

The PHP client is generated with no errors, but when it call the `getItems` method I get this Fatal Error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'AnyOfItemOneItemTwo' not found in /home/user/projects/openapi-test/lib/ObjectSerializer.php:309
Stack trace:
#0 /home/user/projects/openapi-test/lib/ObjectSerializer.php(261): MyRepo\OpenApiTest\ObjectSerializer::deserialize(Object(stdClass), 'AnyOfItemOneIte...', NULL)
#1 /home/user/projects/openapi-test/lib/Api/DefaultApi.php(182): MyRepo\OpenApiTest\ObjectSerializer::deserialize(Array, 'AnyOfItemOneIte...', Array)
#2 /home/user/projects/openapi-test/lib/Api/DefaultApi.php(128): MyRepo\OpenApiTest\Api\DefaultApi->getItemsWithHttpInfo()
#3 /home/user/projects/tests-for-openapi-test/test.php(10): MyRepo\OpenApiTest\Api\DefaultApi->getItems()
#4 {main}
  thrown in /home/user/projects/openapi-test/lib/ObjectSerializer.php on line 309
```

The same occurs if I use the `oneOf` property, but the error I get is: `Uncaught Error: Class 'OneOfItemOneItemTwo' not found...`.

---

My setup works ok when I use any other valid yaml (without the polymorphism).

Also, I checked [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47656791/openapi-multiple-types-inside-an-array) already, but that is about UI, which I'm not using at all.

Do you know where could be the error? A mistake in my yaml doc? A bug in the PHP client generator?

Edit: I'm using openapi-generator v4.0.3 (latest release at this point).

Comment: Is it feasible to share the generated code? Could you also verify the version of the openapi-generator and any flags or additional config used?

Comment: Did you verify the existence of the php class in the generated files? If the class exists it may be a PHP version issue, what version of PHP are you running the files with? If it does not it may be an issue with the generator.

Comment: @ficuscr Not necessary to share the code anymore. I'm using version 4.0.3, where inheritance is broken at the moment. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @DempseyvanWissen The missing class doesn't even exist in the project. This is related with the issue I posted in the answer. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After more researching I found there's an open issue with the inheritance in the openapi-generator from version 4.0.0 onwards.

https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/issues/2845